# Copy files to Default User Profile using PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell

The code below doesn't work as expected. It copies files and directories to all user profiles except the default user's. I am running Powershell with admin privileges.

```
$Source = 'C:\Temp\Teste\*'
$Destination = 'C:\users\*\AppData\Local\'
$Default = 'C:\users\Default\AppData\Local\'
Get-ChildItem $Destination | ForEach-Object {Copy-Item -Path $Source -Destination $_ -Force -Recurse}
Get-ChildItem $Default -Force | ForEach-Object {Copy-Item -Path $Source -Destination $_ -Force -Recurse}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you need to copy all files and folders from the source location to the `%localappdata%` of the Default profile.. It works here if I change the last line to:

```
Copy-Item -Path $Source -Destination $Default -Force
```

To copy recursively (all sub-folders and files from source to destination).

```
Copy-Item -Path $Source -Destination $Default -Force -Recurse
```